# What does "leverages the Apple Watch menu" mean when refusing my App

Tags: app-store-connect

I get the following reason to refuse my app: `Specifically, upon review of application we have application/device icon leverages the Apple Watch menu.`, and they attached my app icon. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Could it mean possibly that your app icon somehow detracts from the design of the home screen or somehow doesn't fit into their design guidelines? That's a I could think of, but I've never heard it stated with that terminology.